# UITableView not scrolling within a UIView container

Tags: swift, uitableview

I'm a swift beginner and I have come across the following issue.

I am displaying a UITableView within a UIView container just fine.

The issue is that the table **will NOT** scroll up/down.

I have read threads on a slightly similar issue and it points to the full table being displayed correctly but it is being clipped by the size of the UIView container, therefore making it not needing to be scrolled as all the cells are being showed.

So my question is, **how do I resize the height of my table to be within the bounds of the View container so that it becomes scrollable?**

[image]

This is my View Controller code:

I declare an outlet to the UIView here

```
@IBOutlet weak var viewOrdersDrinks: UIView!
```

Then I call this function in my viewDidLoad which loads the UITableView into the UIView as a subview.

```
    func loadOrdersDrinks(){

    let listDrinks: CompletedOrderedDrinksListTableViewController = CompletedOrderedDrinksListTableViewController (nibName: "CompletedOrderedDrinksListTableViewController", bundle: nil)

    self.addChildViewController(listDrinks)
    self.viewOrdersDrinks.addSubview(listDrinks.view)

}
```

Comment: Did you check `contentSize` of your tableview?

Comment: what do you mean exactly? - at the moment the table its simply a placeholder displaying 8 cells with a static label in each cell.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you have to autolayout the tableView to fill the parent and here is an UIView extension for this:

```
extension UIView {
    func anchorToSuperview() {
        guard let superview = self.superview else { return }
        self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview.topAnchor).isActive = true
        self.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        self.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        self.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    }
}
```

Another thing to mention is that besides adding the `tableViewController` as a child you have to respect other API calls, related to adding child view controllers. Here is the reference to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html).

All in all, for adding the tableView properly, your code in the end should look something like this:

```
func loadOrdersDrinks() {
    let listDrinks: CompletedOrderedDrinksListTableViewController = CompletedOrderedDrinksListTableViewController (nibName: "CompletedOrderedDrinksListTableViewController", bundle: nil)

    self.addChildViewController(listDrinks)
    self.viewOrdersDrinks.addSubview(listDrinks.tableView)
    self.listDrinks.tableView.anchorToSuperview()
    self.listDrinks.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, although I have tried to integrate it with my code but I am getting an CompletedOrderDetailsViewController has no member listDrinks error at these lines 'self.listDrinks.view.anchorToSuperview()
        self.listDrinks.didMove(toParentViewController: self)'

Comment: extending my tableViewController calls to 'extension CompletedOrderedDrinksListTableViewController:  UIView ' gives a 'Cannot inherit from class UIView'

Comment: just to be clear, I have a TableViewController which I want to load into a UIView managed within a separate ViewController.

Comment: Updated my code, it has to be `self.listDrinks.tableView` instead of the view, for the UITableViewController. But you already had to know that.

Comment: seems to have worked by removing `self` and with just `listDrinks.tableView.anchorToSuperview()`

Comment: Oleg, can the UIView extension be in its own Class?

Comment: The extension to UIView can be with own file.